# Action filter (set) in worksheet

Tags: filter, action, tableau-api, calculation

[image]

Above image is from Filter pane in one worksheet, I want to know how this action filter with set symbol is created -How this is visible in worksheet?  There is filed name pivot field value, but no set created related in to it.
Please explain how to create and show up above filter on worksheet

I Guess: Are dashboard action filters appear in worksheet by default?

Answer (score 0):

Those are the action filters that we use in dashboards and by default there won't be any action filters on worksheets.

Action filters will be added to the filter pane only when that sheet is selected to be a target sheet while creating actions in dashboard.

To know what actions are created and on sheets and dashboard you can go to `Dashboards --> Actions`

You can get more data in this [link](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions.html)